# How to chain in phpquery (almost everything can be a chain)

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

Good day everyone,
  I'm very new with phpquery and this is my first post here at stackoverflow for a reason that i cant find the correct for syntax for the phpquery chaining. I know someone knows what i been looking for.

I only want to remove the a certain div inside a div.

```
 <div id = "content"> 
        <p>The text that i want to display</p>
        <div class="node-links">Stuff i want to remove</div>
 </content>
```

This few lines of codes works perfect

```
 pq('div.node-links')->remove();
 $text = pq('div#content');
 print $text; //output: The text that i want to display
```

But when I tried

```
$text = pq('div#content')->removeClass('div.node-links'); //or
$text = pq('div#content')->remove('div.node-links');

 //output: The text that i want to display (+) Stuff i want to remove
```

Can someone tell me why the second block of code is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of code will only work if your trying to remove the class from `div.node-links`, it won't remove the node.

If you are trying to remove the class you need to change it from:

```
$text = pq('div#content')->removeClass('div.node-links');
// to
$text = pq('div#content')->find('.node-links')->removeClass('node-links')->end();
```

which will output:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>The text that i want to display</p>
    <div>Stuff i want to remove</div>
</div>
```

As for the second line of code.. I'm not exactly sure why it is not working, it seems like your not selecting `.node-links` but I was able to get the desired results using these.

```
// $markup = file_get_contents('test.html');
// $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($markup);
$text = $doc->find('div#content')->children()->remove('.node-links')->end();

// or 

$text = pq('div#content')->find('.node-links')->remove()->end();

// or 

$text = pq('div#content > *')->remove('.node-links')->parent();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you Mr. r-sal, seems like the second one is working

  $text = pq('div#content')->find('.node-links')->remove()->end();

I already find an alternative way, since elements are stored in the database, I added two fields instead, field for fullContent and field for the elements that needed to be remove(). Im developing a dynamic Scrapper for multiple RSS Feeds (i have 200 feed url as of now).

I like phpquery for making scraping more simple, but the only problem is their documentation. Anyway, Thank you so much for this answer, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since `remove()` does not take any parameter, you can do:

```
$text = pq('div#content div.node-links')->remove();
```

Comment: @1mr3yn are you sure your expected div to remove is `node-links`. I can only see div with class `links`?

Comment: sorry my mistake, i will update my post,. I only want to get rid of a certain class inside a div.,

Comment: It seems like `remove()` does take a paramter  https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/phpquery/blob/master/phpQuery/phpQuery/phpQueryObject.php#L1742