# Search for a word in a text-file and delete segments containing this word

Tags: search, replace, language-agnostic, text-files

I want to search for a certain word e.g. "a-files" for example in the href-part and in case of success, I want to remove the whole segment (in this case -> an html-tag) .

```
Don't delete this sentence. <a href="/a-files/X"> Click here - 1 </a> This too..
Don't delete this sentence. <a href="/a-files/Y"> Click here - 2 </a> This too..
Don't delete this sentence. <a href="/b-files/Z"> Click here - 3 </a> This too..
```

In the example above the following part:

```
<a href="/a-files/X"> Click here - 1 </a>
<a href="/a-files/Y"> Click here - 2 </a>
```

should be removed.

How can I do that? (PHP, Bash-Shell, Whatever..)

p.s. A possible way to do that, could be:

```
--> Find the word, 
--> go left, 
--> find "<a", 
--> begin select, 
--> go right, 
--> find "</a>", 
--> end select and 
--> delete this part.
```

Which programming language can do that easly?

p.s. Please consider: the files are not always a html file. I have chosen an html-example, to explain it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). My [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183186/how-to-chain-in-phpquery-almost-everything-can-be-a-chain) here in stackflow is somehow related to your question .

```
$document  = phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML('[file location]'); 
$text = pq('div')->find('a-files')->remove()->end();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, but the files are not always a html file. I have chosen an html-example, to explain it easier.

Comment: try phpQuery::newDocument(); //defaults to text/html in utf8
see phpQuery Initialize - http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/#INITIALIZE_IT